# fetch sqs message visibility_timeout in aws using ruby

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

in sqs, is there any way i can get visibility_timeout of a message?
I plan to double visibility_timeout every it's expired. If SQS has no such API can fetch visibility_timeout of a message, i will need maintain a separate mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax to get the visibility time our for an SQS queue. That `GetQueueAttributes` will give you the value for visibility time out.

```
http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/testQueue/
?Action=GetQueueAttributes
&AttributeName.1=All
&Version=2012-11-05
&Expires=2013-10-18T22%3A52%3A43PST
&AUTHPARAMS
```

The response for above request will be as follows.

```
<GetQueueAttributesResponse>
  <GetQueueAttributesResult>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds</Name>
      <Value>2</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>VisibilityTimeout</Name>
      <Value>30</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>ApproximateNumberOfMessages</Name>
      <Value>0</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible</Name>
      <Value>0</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>CreatedTimestamp</Name>
      <Value>1286771522</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>LastModifiedTimestamp</Name>
      <Value>1286771522</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>QueueArn</Name>
      <Value>arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:qfoo</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>MaximumMessageSize</Name>
      <Value>8192</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>MessageRetentionPeriod</Name>
      <Value>345600</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </GetQueueAttributesResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>1ea71be5-b5a2-4f9d-b85a-945d8d08cd0b</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetQueueAttributesResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you understand [Visibility Timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AboutVT.html) from the developer guide.

The visibility timer starts when you receive the message.  There is no way to interrogate it on a message that has been received - - you can calculate it from the received time by subtracting the queue's default from how long you've been sitting on the message... or by subtracting the time since you last set it's visibility timeout, from the amount of time you set it to.

Doubling the timeout is probably not the best plan, since it has a maximum value which you could inadvertently hit after a few doublings, and in many or most applications, increasing visibility timeout should be unnecessary.  This could be a sign that you are contemplating a use of S3 outside its intended design.

Also, an individual queue is limited to 120,000 in-flight messages, which includes any message you have received but not deleted  - - including all those whose visibility timeout, whether default or extended - - has not expired.

And, changing a message's visibility timeout constitutes a billable request to the SQS API.

> All SQS API calls count as a Request
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/

Better, perhaps, just default it to a reasonable value, and update it by a reasonable amount of time, if updates are necessary.  Once you process and delete the message, the visibility timeout becomes meaningless.